# How does a compiler know that an identifier in an expression refers to a memory location, or the value stored at that location?

Tags: compilers, implementation

There are situations during compilation when some identifier represents a particular value ("contained" in a variable, etc), but sometimes it references the variable's memory location directly.

How does the compiler know which is intended, to generate the correct code?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about *rvalues* vs *lvalues*, to use the C++ terminology. Is that correct?

Comment: In essence yes. But there are situations where you would still treat an lvalue like an rvalue, depending on context, but I have been struggling to implement this all correctly in my  own compiler project

Answer (score 5):

The easy way of answering this is to just define, in each grammatical context, whether the name of a reference means the reference itself or the referenced value. So if `x` is a reference, and a reference in a simple name expression means a reference, then `x + 7` gives a type error; inconvenient, but easy for the compiler. Then it's the user's responsibility to write `*x + 7` when they want the referenced value. However, even strongly-typed languages like Rust usually aren't this pedantic about references.

The more ergonomic way of doing it is by implicit coercions, using information about static types. Let's use a more familiar example from Java:

```java
int x = 5;
System.out.println(x + 2.5);
```

Here the variable `x` is an integer, but its value must be a `double` for the expression `x + 2.5` to make sense. The compiler knows (based on the static types of the expressions) that the expression `x` is expected to produce a `double` but it is actually of type `int`, and so it inserts a coercion from `int` to `double`.

Likewise, consider the following Rust code:

```rust
let x_val = 5;
let x_ref = &x_val;
print!("{}", x_ref + 7);
```

In this code, `x_ref` has type `&i32`, a reference to an integer. But in the expression `x_ref + 7`, an `i32` is expected. The Rust compiler knows both of these facts, because of the static type of `x_ref` and the static type expected by the `+` operator (given that its other operand is an integer), so it inserts a coercion from `&i32` to `i32` by dereferencing.

Answer (score 4):

What I think you're referring to, but correct me if you meant something else, is this problem:

When looking at a node in my AST that refers to a variable (or worse, something else that can have its address taken), how do I know whether to emit IR/code to take its address, or to load its value?

And well, you don't. It depends on the context in which it is used. So you only know that one level up, and maybe not even then (consider a chain of `record.field.field.field` nodes). So here are three things you could do about it, while walking over your AST:

- One option is to pass down a flag that says whether you want the value or the address.
- Another option is to pass *up* the fact that you implicitly took the address of a variable, and then let it be up to the AST node that uses that thing. The address-of operator would turn that implicitly-taken address into a normal value that just happens to be an address, if it's the target of an assignment then you can store to the address, if it's used in a value context then you dereference the implicitly-taken address there. This option would tend to spam your IR with things that need to be optimized out while it may be non-trivial to do so.
- Another option is having two different "visitors" (one for value contexts and another for address contexts) that use each other as required.

There is a similar distinction between evaluating a comparison for the purpose of branching on it, or for reifying it into an actual boolean that can be stored somewhere.